# Filter DOORS on historical data

Tags: ibm-doors

Is there a way to filter based on historical data?
For example: "Show me all objects who had "Attribute_X" == True on 01/01/2013"

Comment: You could do this, but it would require an advanced DXL script that looked at the history of each object and rolled back any changes to the specified date. Also if the date was before a baseline, the script would need to open the baseline to find the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

As Steve stated, this would require an advanced DXL script.

I'm not sure about creating a filter on this, but identifying those objects you are looking for, I might be able to help. Having recently solved a similar task, I recommend to start with Tony Goodman's really excellent [Smart History Viewer](http://www.smartdxl.com/content/?p=418) (this code could be used as DXL tutorial!) which has almost all the code you need. You just need to find and understand it.

Let me elaborate. Besides other nifty stuff, the history viewer basically does:

For all (selected) baselines, explicitly including un-baselined current version: gather all module changes and put them into a two-dimensional Skip list each, for module/object/session changes. Focus on the object changes.

There is an unused function `printObjectHistory` in the code which helps understanding the data structures. Have a look at the inner loop

```
for hist in skipHistory do
```

Inside this loop, consider only changes which happened before "01/01/2013" (check `hist->HIST_DATE` to obtain this information). The history viewer code already classified the detected changes, so you want to watch out for changes which contain the string "Modify Attribute: Attribute_X". Assign the new value to a buffer. Outside this loop, check if the buffer contains "True". If so, you this is one of the objects you wanted to find.